# My react-native app keeps stopping after build

Tags: react-native, expo

I have built a QR scanner app with expo & react native
it works fine on Expo and I could build it into APK successfully but when try to open the app from my Android phone it keeps stopping

this is my app.js full code
I don`t know why it`s crashing I`ve checked the code for any errors but nothing was found
this is my app.js full code
I also tried to build it 3 times and make sure that the code is working on my android phone using the expo app from google play

```
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";

// Import necessary components from React and Expo
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {
  View,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
  StyleSheet,
  Image,
} from "react-native";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/native-stack";
import { Camera } from "expo-camera";

// Create a Stack Navigator
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();


// Home Page Component
const Home = ({ navigation }) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.headerText}>Welcome in Lifete</Text>
      <Text style={styles.h2Text}>App Info: Tickets Scanner</Text>
      <Text style={styles.h2Text}>Developer: Lifete Team</Text>
      <Text style={styles.h2Text}>App Version: 1.0</Text>
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={styles.scanButton}
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate("QRScanner")}
      >
        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Scan QR Code</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};

// Login Page Component
const Login = ({ navigation }) => {
  // State variables to store the entered username and password
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [UsetKey, setKey] = useState("");

  // Function to handle the login button press
  const handleLogin = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        "https://lifete-eg.com/api/Mobile/API/User",
        {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            Accept: "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            Key: '-----',
            UserEmail: username,
            UserPassword: password,
          }),
        }
      );
      const json = await response.json();
     
      // Perform authentication logic here (dummy logic for illustration)
      if (json.Status == 'True') {
        // Navigate to the Home page on successful login
        setKey(json.Key);
        navigation.navigate("Home");
      } else {
        // Handle incorrect login credentials
        alert("Invalid username or password");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.headerText}>Login</Text>
      <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        placeholder="Username"
        onChangeText={(text) => setUsername(text)}
        value={username}
      />
      <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        placeholder="Password"
        secureTextEntry={true}
        onChangeText={(text) => setPassword(text)}
        value={password}
      />
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.loginButton} onPress={handleLogin}>
        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Login</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};


const QRScanner = () => {
  const [hasPermission, setHasPermission] = useState(null);
  const [scannedData, setScannedData] = useState("");
  const cameraRef = React.useRef(null);

  // Declare the Ticket Details Vars
  const [Plan, setTicketPlan] = useState("Waiting");
  const [TicketScanned, setTicketScanned] = useState("Waiting");
  const [TicketScannedColor, setTicketScannedColor] = useState("red");
  const [TicketScannedText, setTicketScannedText] = useState("Waiting");
  const [EventTitle, setTicketEventTilte] = useState("Waiting");
  const [AttendeeName, setTicketAttName] = useState("Waiting");
  const [AttendeeEmail, setTicketAttEmail] = useState("Waiting");
  const [AttendeePhone, setTicketAttPhone] = useState("Waiting");
  const [AttendeePhoto, setTicketAttPhoto] = useState("https://placehold.co/600x1000");
  const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(false);

  const requestCameraPermission = async () => {
    const { status } = await Camera.requestPermissionsAsync();
    setHasPermission(status === "granted");
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    requestCameraPermission();
  }, []);

  const handleBarCodeScanned = async({ data }) => {
    if(scannedData == data){
      return;
    }
    setScannedData(data);
 
    // send to server API to get ticket details
    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        "https://lifete-eg.com/api/Mobile/API/Ticket",
        {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            Accept: "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            Key: '------',
            Ticket: 2954511257
          }),
        }
      );
      
      const json = await response.json();
     
      // Perform authentication logic here (dummy logic for illustration)
      if (json.Status == 'True') {
        // Display Ticket Details
        
        setTicketPlan(json.Ticket.Plan);
        setTicketScanned(json.Ticket.Scanned);
        if(TicketScanned == '1'){
          setTicketScannedText('Used');
          setTicketScannedColor('red');
        }else{
          setTicketScannedText('Registered');
          setTicketScannedColor('green');
        }
        


        setTicketEventTilte(json.Ticket.EventTitle);
        setTicketAttName(json.Ticket.AttendeeName);
        setTicketAttEmail(json.Ticket.AttendeeEmail);
        setTicketAttPhone(json.Ticket.AttendeePhone);
        setTicketAttPhoto(json.Ticket.AttendeePhoto);


        
        


      } else {
        alert(json.Status);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  if (hasPermission === null) {
    return <View />;
  }
  if (hasPermission === false) {
    return <Text>No access to camera</Text>;
  }

  return (
    <View style={stylesQR.container}>
      {/* Part 1: Camera with padding and border-radius */}
      <View style={stylesQR.cameraContainer}>
        <Camera
          ref={cameraRef}
          style={stylesQR.camera}
          type={Camera.Constants.Type.back}
          onBarCodeScanned={handleBarCodeScanned}
        />
      </View>

      <View style={stylesQR.infoContainer}>
        <View style={[{ width: "55%" }]}>
          <View style={[stylesQR.infoItem, { width: "95%" }]}>
            <Text style={stylesQR.infoText}>Name:</Text>
            <Text style={stylesQR.infoValue}>{AttendeeName}</Text>
            <Text style={stylesQR.infoText}>Email:</Text>
            <Text style={stylesQR.infoValue}>{AttendeeEmail}</Text>
            <Text style={stylesQR.infoText}>Phone:</Text>
            <Text style={stylesQR.infoValue}>{AttendeePhone}</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={[stylesQR.infoItem, { width: "95%" }]}>
            <Text style={stylesQR.infoText}>Event:</Text>
            <Text style={[stylesQR.infoValue, { fontSize: 16 }]}>
              {EventTitle}
            </Text>
            <Text style={stylesQR.infoText}>Ticket:</Text>
            <Text style={[stylesQR.infoValue, { fontSize: 18, color: "gold" }]}>
              {Plan}
            </Text>
            <Text style={stylesQR.infoText}>Status:</Text>
            <Text style={[stylesQR.infoValue, { fontSize: 18, color: TicketScannedColor}]}>
             {TicketScannedText}
            </Text>
          </View>
        </View>

        <View style={[stylesQR.infoItem, [{ borderWidth: 0 }]]}>
          <Image
            source={{ uri: AttendeePhoto }} // Replace with your desired face image URL
            style={[
              stylesQR.infoImage,
              { borderWidth: 1, borderColor: "gray", borderRadius: 10 },
            ]}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

const stylesQR = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: "column"
  },
  cameraContainer: {
    flex: 0.4,
    padding: "10%",
    borderRadius: 100,
    overflow: "hidden"
  },
  camera: {
    flex: 1,
    borderRadius: 10
  },
  infoContainer: {
    flex: 0.6,
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "space-around",
    padding: 16
  },
  infoItem: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: "gray",
    borderRadius: 10,
    margin: 8,
    padding: 8
  },
  infoText: {
    fontSize: 11,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    marginBottom: 4
  },
  infoValue: {
    fontSize: 12,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    marginBottom: 5
  },
  infoImage: {
    width: "105%",
    height: 200,
    resizeMode: "contain"
  },
});

// App Component
const App = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Login">
        <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
        <Stack.Screen name="QRScanner" component={QRScanner} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

// Styles for the components
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    padding: 16
  },
  headerText: {
    fontSize: 24,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    marginBottom: 20
  },
  h2Text: {
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    marginBottom: 30,
    marginTop: 30
  },
  input: {
    width: "100%",
    height: 40,
    borderColor: "gray",
    borderWidth: 1,
    marginBottom: 20,
    padding: 10
  },
  loginButton: {
    backgroundColor: "#c5a471",
    padding: 10,
    borderRadius: 5
  },
  buttonText: {
    color: "white",
    textAlign: "center",
    fontWeight: "bold",
    backgroundColor: "#c5a471"
  },
  scanButton: {
    backgroundColor: "#c5a471",
    padding: 20,
    borderRadius: 5,
    marginTop: 20
  },
  camera: {
    flex: 1,
    width: "100%"
  },
  scannedDataText: {
    marginTop: 10,
    fontSize: 16
  },
});

export default App;
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Check android `logcat`. Without any error info, it'll be difficult to help you.